# How to check that Node JS is installed correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I'm completely new to OSX. I've tried to install Node JS using Terminal following step-by-step tutorial. How do I check that Node JS is installed successfully? Are there any commands or GUI interface equivalent to "Programs and Features" in Windows?

Thanks,
DV

Comment: node -v or node --version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `node -v` in the terminal and you should see the node version displayed if its installed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Does this apply to any programs on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

> The node.js executable (binary) should be node, not nodejs. However,
>   there was a naming conflict on some Linux distros (e.g., Ubuntu),
>   resulting in the executable getting installed as nodejs. As of Ubuntu
>   14.04, for instance, apt-get install nodejs will also install executable node (implemented as a symlink to nodejs). In other words:
>   For consistency, try node -v first.

$ node -v

if symlink was used

$ nodejs -v